# Azure B2C Custom policy / custom ui - Embed 'password reset' and 'sign up' button from a different page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a Azure B2C custom login page which displays 'sign in' text fields, 'sign up' and 'password reset' links.
[image]

How can we add only 'sign up' and 'password reset' buttons in a different page of the application.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a custom policy or built in user flow

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal  Custom Policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it outside B2C.
You can host your own page and have two links for Sign up and Forgot password. Signup link can point to Signup userflow/policy link and Forgot Password link can point to forgot password userflow link.